# Android NFC scan error callback

Tags: android, callback, nfc

I'm currently working on NFC reading app and I encountered this problem:

Normally when I scan a tag, I'm able to hear a sound that marks success in scanning and my app detects the tag.

But sometimes, if I scan tags with little delay between each scan, I hear different sound, that possibly signals error during scanning and my app doesn't detect the tag.

After a brief delay, I'm able to scan same tag successfully.

I wanted to ask, is there any possibility to detect this kind of situation and notify the user to wait and try to scan tag again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @KCN that's what I would like to do, the real question is, how do I detect when toast should be shown?

Comment: if card not scanned properly Toast your message.Check card Scanning or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Android only notifies apps when a tag was successfully read and does not provide any means to be notified when tag reading was interruped/has failed.

On a rooted device you might be able to use a dynamic modification framework such as Xposed to modify the behavior of the NFC service in order to detect such events. For instance, you could hook the method `playSound()` of the NFC service (see [NfcService.java:625](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/android-5.0.0_r7/src/com/android/nfc/NfcService.java#625)) and check if it was called with the parameter `SOUND_ERROR` (assuming that sounds are played when reading failed).

Still, this could only notify your app when the lower layers of the NFC stack notified the NFC system service about the tag scan. If reading was interrupted earlier in the lower part of the NFC stack or if the NFC controller did not even pass any information about the tag scan to the host system, you would still not be able to discover this.